# Remote video streaming using Janus-gateway not displaying in react-native

Tags: react-native, janus-gateway

I am trying to display a remote streaming video using janus gateway in my react native project. 
I am using this package: https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc to display the streaming video in my component and janus library (janus.mobile.js file) from here https://github.com/atyenoria/react-native-webrtc-janus-gateway/blob/master/src/janus.mobile.js

My onremotestream function is triggered but i keep receiving  a black screen instead of my streaming video.( both android and ios )

I am using react-native-webrtc v : 1.75.3
react-native : 0.60.5

I call Janus this way in my component:
Here's my code:

`export default class VideoExample extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
        containerStreaming = this;

```
    Janus.init({debug: "all", callback: function() {
            if(started)
                return;
            started = true;
        }});

    this.janusStart();
}

janusStart = () => {
    containerStreaming.setState({ visible: true });
            let janus = new Janus({
                server: containerStreaming.props.server,
                iceServers: containerStreaming.props.iceServers,
                token: containerStreaming.props.token,

                success: function() {
                    janus.attach({
                        plugin: "janus.plugin.streaming",

                        success: function(pluginHandle) {
                            streaming = pluginHandle;
                            Janus.log(`Janus Plugin Attached : ${pluginHandle.getId()}`);
                            streaming.send({ "message": {"request": "watch", id: containerStreaming.props.id } });
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            Janus.error(`Error Attaching Janus Plugin ${error}`)
                        },
                        mediaState: function(medium, on) {
                            containerStreaming.setState({status: 'stopped', info: 'Stopped'});
                            Janus.log("Janus " + (on ? "started" : "stopped") + " receiving our " + medium);
                        },
                        webrtcState: function(on) {
                            console.log("Janus says our WebRTC PeerConnection is " + (on ? "up" : "down") + " now");
                            // $("#videolocal").parent().parent().unblock();
                        },
                        onmessage: function(msg, jsep) {
                            console.log("jsep" ,jsep.sdp);
                            Janus.log(`Janus Message received : ${JSON.stringify(msg)} and jsep ${jsep}`);
                            var result = msg['result'];
                            if (!!result && result['status'] == 'stopped') {
                                janus.destroy();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (jsep !== null && jsep !== undefined) {
                                Janus.log(`JANUS : Handling SDP as well : ${jsep}`);
                                streaming.createAnswer({
                                    jsep: jsep,
                                    media: { audioSend: false, videoSend: false }, // recvonly
                                    success: function(jsep){
                                        Janus.debug(`Janus Got SDP : ${jsep}`);
                                        streaming.send({ message: { request: 'start' }, jsep: jsep });
                                    },
                                    error: function(error) {
                                        Janus.error(`Janus WebRTC error : ${error}`)
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        onremotestream: function(stream) {
                            Janus.log('Janus Remote stream detected');
                            Janus.log(stream);
                            containerStreaming.setState({status: 'streaming', info: 'Streaming'});
                            containerStreaming.setState({selfViewSrc: stream.toURL()});
                        },
                        oncleanup: function() {
                            Janus.log('Janus clean up notification')
                        }
                    })
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    Janus.error('Janus  -- ' + error);
                    Janus.error('Destroying Janus');
                    janus.destroy();
                },
                destroyed: function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                },

            });
};
```

`

`render() {
        return (
             <RTCView
                        zOrder={0}
                        streamURL={this.state.selfViewSrc}
                        style={styles.streamingStyle} />
        );};
}`

Answer (score 0):

The same story with desktop chromium app with cefsharp.Net